# How to anchor Quasar QInput/QSelect placeholder label at top and within the QInput/QSelect boxes even when no data added or selected in them?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

How to anchor placeholder label at top and within the QInput/QSelect boxes even when no data added or selected in them?

I am requesting this to avoid users assuming that data already added in the fields on first look.

What I expect is the positioning of the label as in the Display Name field below with no data added in it.

It should NOT be like in the User Name and Password fields.
[image]

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prop for this 'stack-label'

> stack-label : Boolean 
> Label will be always shown above the field regardless of field content
> (if any)

[documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#qinput-api)

**code example**

```
<q-input v-model="text" label="Display Name" stack-label />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I somehow missed that prop. Thank you again.